# How to fix Woocommerce gallery dosn't work in Wordpress site

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, visual-composer

The woocommerce gallery doesn't work if i upload multi images for product, but the image work if useed single image, I deactivated all plugins one by one, and found that gallery works if deactivated WPBakery Visual comproser plugin, but many pages down if deactivated visual comproser.
[Sample product page](https://shop.demoz.site/product/game-console-controller-usb-3-0-cable/)
May anyone check this issue plz?

Comment: are all your plugins up to date? have you tried to change theme?

Comment: @Syntax_Error It seems like the theme disabled update in the free demo, i added the wp-config code: define( 'AUTOMATIC_UPDATER_DISABLED', true );
define( 'WP_AUTO_UPDATE_CORE', true );
But the update page still not shown, is it a way to enable update feature?